using google authentication in the Automation testing of android application
I am working on the automation testing using Appium and Java for an Android application. The Android application uses Google authentication for the users. I have disabled the 2 factor authentication in Google settings for the gmail account and allowed less secure apps.
When the automation is running, still the notification is sent to the last logged in device. Since I am running in cloud based software testing systems like LambdaTest and BrowserStack, the last executed device isn't accessible, and each time the execution occurs on different Android mobiles.
I have tried 2 ways to do the automation.

Used the below capabilities.
playstorelogin.put("email", "automationuser@gmail.com");          
playstorelogin.put("password", "Pass@123");          
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appium:playStoreLogin", 
    playstorelogin);


Entered the username and password in the corresponding mobile elements and submitted.


Still in both cases, getting the notification for additional security measure
Google Login has other solutions like backup codes that can be passed, but it allows to generate only 8 codes at a time, which can't be used since it will be used within a day as I have to execute on more than 10 devices in a stretch.
Is there any other way to achieve Google authentication using automation without second level authentication on multiple devices ?
